# How to get fitted values(insample forecast) for model where fitted=True is not implemented in StatsForecast Library

Tags: python, forecasting, forecast, statsforecast

I am using [StatsForecast](https://github.com/Nixtla/statsforecast) library. I am using combination of models to fit the forecast. My data is sparse (demand is zero for most of the values) and I want to use sparse model which is there in statsforecast (https://github.com/Nixtla/statsforecast)

The issue with these models are, insample forecast is not available for these methods.
It is available for AutoArima and Naive Method.
The below code is working fine for AutoARIMA and Naive Model

```
sf = StatsForecast(df=df_train_sf,
    models=[AutoARIMA(season_length = 52),
    Naive(), 
     ], 
    freq='W')


y_pred = sf.forecast(
X_df = df_val_sf.drop('y', axis=1),
    fitted = True,
    h=h)

insample_forecasts = sf.forecast_fitted_values().reset_index()
insample_forecasts.head(1)
```

But if I am using model such as CrostonClassic(), IMAPA(),ADIDA() then insample forecasting is not available.

```
sf = StatsForecast(df=df_train_sf,
    models=[CrostonClassic(),
      IMAPA(),
      ADIDA(), 
     ], 
    freq='W')

y_pred = sf.forecast(
X_df = df_val_sf.drop('y', axis=1),
    fitted = True,
    h=h)
```

Please let me know how to resolve this?
One Hack is to use the training data and forecast on the same data. But I am not sure that is doable in forecasting as for method like Naive, this is completely a wrong approach as last obs of training data will get forecasted for the entire training data.

I am looking for hack or use other alternative libraries with the same speed and methods implemented

I am pasting the error below in case you want to dig deeper.

> ---

NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call

> last) Cell In[170], line 12
> 2 df_val_sf = df_val_sf[df_val_sf.unique_id=='290~1-290~112146371']
> 4 sf = StatsForecast(df=df_train_sf,
> 5     models=[CrostonClassic(),
> 6       IMAPA(),
> 7       ADIDA(),
> 8      ],
> 9     freq='W')
> ---> 12 y_pred = sf.forecast(
> 13 X_df = df_val_sf.drop('y', axis=1),
> 14     fitted = True,
> 15     h=h)
>
> File
> /opt/conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsforecast/core.py:1899,
> in StatsForecast.forecast(self, h, df, X_df, level, fitted, sort_df,
> prediction_intervals)    1895     raise ValueError(    1896
> "You must specify `level` when using `prediction_intervals`"    1897
> )    1898 if self._is_native(df=df):
> -> 1899     return super().forecast(    1900         h=h,    1901         df=df,    1902         X_df=X_df,    1903         level=level,    1904
> fitted=fitted,    1905         sort_df=sort_df,    1906
> prediction_intervals=prediction_intervals,    1907     )    1908
> assert df is not None    1909 engine =
> make_execution_engine(infer_by=[df])
>
> File
> /opt/conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsforecast/core.py:1087,
> in _StatsForecast.forecast(self, h, df, X_df, level, fitted, sort_df,
> prediction_intervals)    1085 X, level = self._parse_X_level(h=h,
> X=X_df, level=level)    1086 if self.n_jobs == 1:
> -> 1087     res_fcsts = self.ga.forecast(    1088         models=self.models,    1089         h=h,    1090
> fallback_model=self.fallback_model,    1091         fitted=fitted,
> 1092         X=X,    1093         level=level,    1094
> verbose=self.verbose,    1095     )    1096 else:    1097
> res_fcsts = self._forecast_parallel(h=h, fitted=fitted, X=X,
> level=level)
>
> File
> /opt/conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsforecast/core.py:207,
> in GroupedArray.forecast(self, models, h, fallback_model, fitted, X,
> level, verbose)
> 198         res_i = fallback_model.forecast(
> 199             h=h,
> 200             y=y_train,    (...)
> 204             **kwargs,
> 205         )
> 206     else:
> --> 207         raise error
> 208 cols_m = [
> 209     key
> 210     for key in res_i.keys()
> 211     if any(key.startswith(m) for m in matches)
> 212 ]
> 213 fcsts_i = np.vstack([res_i[key] for key in cols_m]).T
>
> File
> /opt/conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsforecast/core.py:193,
> in GroupedArray.forecast(self, models, h, fallback_model, fitted, X,
> level, verbose)
> 191     kwargs["level"] = level
> 192 try:
> --> 193     res_i = model.forecast(
> 194         h=h, y=y_train, X=X_train, X_future=X_f, fitted=fitted, **kwargs
> 195     )
> 196 except Exception as error:
> 197     if fallback_model is not None:
>
> File
> /opt/conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsforecast/models.py:4074,
> in CrostonClassic.forecast(self, y, h, X, X_future, level, fitted)
> 4039 def forecast(    4040     self,    4041     y: np.ndarray,
> (...)    4046     fitted: bool = False,    4047 ):    4048
> """Memory Efficient CrostonClassic predictions.    4049     4050
> This method avoids memory burden due from object storage.    (...)
> 4072         Dictionary with entries `mean` for point predictions and
> `level_*` for probabilistic predictions.    4073     """
> -> 4074     res = _croston_classic(y=y, h=h, fitted=fitted)    4075     if level is None:    4076         return res
>
> File
> /opt/conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsforecast/models.py:3915,
> in _croston_classic()    3908 @njit    3909 def _croston_classic(
> 3910     y: np.ndarray,  # time series    3911     h: int,  #
> forecasting horizon    3912     fitted: bool,  # fitted values    3913
> ):    3914     if fitted:
> -> 3915         raise NotImplementedError("return fitted")    3916     yd = _demand(y)    3917     yi = _intervals(y)
>
> NotImplementedError: return fitted

Comment: Hey. Those models don't have support for predicting the training data, can you open an issue for that here: https://github.com/Nixtla/statsforecast/issues/new/choose, please?